# -WPF Model-View-ViewModel- ItemSources for ListBox is available after a connection to DataBase

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I have a `WPF Application` and I want to use `Model-View-ViewModel pattern`. So, I created my `Model` class, my `View` (`XAML`) and my ViewModel as a bridge between them. The ViewModel has a `ObservableCollection` used to fill the content of a `ListBox`. So, in my XAML I binded the `ItemSources` to the name of my list.
Anyway my method fillMyDataStructure() is called only when the Application is started.

My problem is that the list is not filled at Application startup. User clicks on Connection to Database Button and only if the connection is successfully the list is filled. But my ListBox is empty because the Application tries to fill it only at startup, when the list is empty of cource. So, how can I fix this issue, staying faithful to Model-View-ViewModel pattern? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you forgot implement the INotifyPropertyChanged. You need to inform your View about changes in your ViewModel if you replace the whole ObservableCollection. Have a look at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0b73e1/mvvm-model-view-viewmodel-introduction-part-3/

Comment: I think you forgot to include code to reproduce your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

What you need is detection of change in list. There are two ways you might need. One is to detect when property containing collection has changed (ie. you set it to another collection instance). Another is when collection itself is changed (when you add or remove items).
Second one you solved by using ObservableCollection.
For first one, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise `PropertyChanged` event for your collection property.
You can easily find example for implementation of this interface.

Comment: Thank you. I do it. The fact is I do "this.DataContext = new myViewModel()" and only in myViewModel the list is filled, not in a following moment when the connect to DB is done. Maybe the correct solution is to create an event connectedDB, raise it when a connection is established and set only in that moment the DataContext. What do you think about it?

Comment: I think you should edit your question and add relevant parts of code :)  
For more precise answer we need more precise question (which means code).